# How many gifts can a Werewolf have active at once?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse, werewolf-20th-anniversary

Most gifts have a duration and last until it expires (generally a scene). So, could a werewolf stack gifts like Razor Claws and Luna's Armor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## There is no limit.

I've just read over the rules for Gifts in W20, and there does not seem to be any mention of a limit on the number of Gifts a werewolf can use at once. However, many Gifts require actions to activate, payments of points of Rage or Gnosis to activate, or other costs like taking a box of Lethal or Aggravated damage. As a result, having an extremely large number of Gifts active at once is likely to be difficult.

Comment: some gifts are exclusive to one another to